Updated to Ubuntu's latest version via update manager. No longer opens window manager
I recently (less than two hours ago) updated from 22.04 to the latest version of Ubuntu. As far as I could tell, everything went well until I saw that the machine would no longer boot to the normal Ubuntu gui login screen.
What did I do wrong (if anything) and how do I fix this?

It is hard to understand what is the current situation. Does Ubuntu open? Does grub screen open? Does Windows open?

It opens into a plain terminal; the    Ubuntu desktop does not open. It's not a dual-boot machine, so Windows doesn't exist.

From a command line append to you question the output of 'systemctl status gdm3'

Update your original question with the actual Ubuntu version you upgraded to. Saying a vague "latest version of Ubuntu" does not help. I have seen several reports of this sort behavior (missing GUI) on recent upgrades to 24.04 LTS and when I recently upgraded several machines I had the problem on one of them. I can't say what will fix yours but for me it turned out a simple fix was to do: sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop

This question is similar to: How to fix broken 24.04.1 LTS upgrade which is missing necessary software?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
